# TclError for no reason

Tags: python, tkinter

> self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-class"

I am trying to make a calculator that solves for square roots (But in tkinter). Something simple. What was supposed to happen is that you enter in a number in the entry box, press a button, and then you see the answer below. However, whenever I press the button the get the answer, I get tkinter.TclError. I have tried everything including making the function differently, packing in a different order, whatevver seemed logical. Nothing worked. Please help! Code is below.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as fnt
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')
res = Label(root, text='The answer will go here.')
from math import sqrt
myfont = fnt.Font(font='Helvetica',size=50)
head = Label(text='The Square root Solver!',font=myfont)
head.pack()
txtbox = Entry(root)
txtbox.pack()
def print_ans():
    def solve():
        from math import sqrt
        return sqrt(eval(txtbox.get()))
    ans = solve()
    res.configure(root, text=f'The square root of {txtbox.get()} is {ans}')
submit = Button(root, text='Submit', command=print_ans)
submit.pack()
res.pack()[enter image description here][1]

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you passing `root` as a parameter to `res.configure()?`  (I'm assuming that's where the error occurs - please always include the complete traceback message.)

Comment: ok hold on adding the traceback message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Turned out, I really am bad at tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying too hard. `eval`, importing `font`, storing a reference to every widget even if you will never use the reference, nested functions ~ None of this is necessary.

Here's a minimalist example

```
import tkinter as tk
import math

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')

tk.Label(root, text='The Square root Solver!', font='Helvetica 20').pack()

results = tk.Label(root)
results.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

cmd = lambda f=entry.get: results.configure(text=f'The square root of {f()} is {math.sqrt(float(f()))}')

tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=cmd).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Python 3.8+ version

```
import tkinter as tk
import math

(root := tk.Tk()).geometry('500x400')

tk.Label(root, text='The Square root Solver!', font='Helvetica 20').pack()

(results := tk.Label(root)).pack()

(entry := tk.Entry(root)).pack()

cmd = lambda f=entry.get: results.configure(text=f'The square root of {f()} is {math.sqrt(float(f()))}')

tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=cmd).pack()

root.mainloop()
```